# Convert Subversion repository to CVS

Tags: svn, cvs

Are there any tools/techniques to convert (downgrade) an existing SVN repository to (old-fashioned) CVS? I know that both are not equivalent in features, but is there some way to do it with minimal loss and keeping most of the history?

Comment: why would you do this? migrate to GIT instead if you must get away from SVN.

Comment: it's not my wish, we tried all our arguments to convince the client to not do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, since you must...

i have never faced this issue but some google search gave me those links:

```
http://svn2cvs.tigris.org/
```

and

```
http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2009-January/031846.html
```

please note that i do not endorse this idea at all :)

Comment: Neither do I :) Thanks for the links